# TypeError on CORS for flask-restful

Tags: python, flask, cors, flask-restful

While trying the new CORS feature on flask-restful, I found out that the decorator can be only applied if the function returns a string.

For example, modifying the [Quickstart example](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html):

```
class HelloWorld(restful.Resource):
    @cors.crossdomain(origin='*')
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}
```

Throws:

`TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently came across this issue myself.  @MartijnPieters is correct, `decorators` can't be called on single methods of the view.

<strike>I created an abstract base class that contained the `decorator` list.  The class that consumes `Resource` (from flask-restful) also inherits the base class, which is the class actually applying the decorator list to the view.</strike>

```
    class AbstractAPI():
       decorators = [cors.crossdomain(origin='*')]

    class HelloWorld(restful.Resource, AbstractAPI):
       #content
```

nope.

just add the decorator list to the parameters after you create the Api instance

```
api = Api(app)
api.decorators=[cors.crossdomain(origin='*')]
```

Comment: Also, add `from flask_restful.utils import cors`

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the wrapped function is passed (as one argument) to [`flask.make_response()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.make_response); anything that a *normal* Flask view can return is acceptable. The decorator is essentially the same as [this Flask snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/56/).

Because the Flask-restful `Resource` is a subclass of [`flask.views.MethodView`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/views/#method-based-dispatching) you should really *not* put decorators directly on the methods here. As documented in [Decorating Views](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/views/#decorating-views) you should list view decorators in a special class attribute, `decorators` which is a list:

```
class HelloWorld(restful.Resource):
    decorators = [cors.crossdomain(origin='*')]

    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}
```

and Flask will apply the view to the actual view method returned by `HelloWorld.as_view()`, which is what Flask actually calls when dispatching the route to the view.

Applying them directly to the methods will only server to confuse the `restful.Resource` dispatcher as it is expecting methods to return python datastructures suitable for encoding to JSON, which is not what `cors.crossdomain()` returns anyway.

Comment: @user3022063: Really? That is very curious, because those don't get applied until `HelloWorld.as_view()` is called, which means they are not applied to `get()` but to the dispatcher, so **after** `restful.Resource` has turned your method response into JSON.

Comment: Indeed, that is not what happens, maybe because flask-restful Resources are not Pluggable Views, but something different.

Comment: @miracle2k: they are pluggable views, but quite specialised.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can still use the decorator provided you return a string or JSON response (which is probably good practice for an API anyway). This is important if you want to do route-specific CORS headers, using the decorator makes life much easier. See this merged pull req for more information: https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/pull/131

Here's an example:

```
from . import app
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource
from flask.ext.cors import cross_origin
from datetime import datetime
from flask import jsonify

api = Api(app)


class DateTime(Resource):
    @cross_origin(origins="http://localhost:63342*")
    def get(self):
        return jsonify({'DateTime': str(datetime.today())})

api_root = '/api/v1/'
api.add_resource(DateTime, api_root + 'DateTime')
```

If you're using flask-security, adding auth decorators had some weird behavior in my testing. I recommend `assert current_user.is_authenticated` instead. If you are allowing credentials, make sure to CSRF protect.

Comment: The whole *point* of using Flask-Restful is to make your API *response encoding agnostic*. Flask-Restful takes responsibility to encode to an accepted response encoding, such as XML, JSON, or anything else you teach it to do, based on content negotiation with the client.